# android gps client sending coordinates to server only if within an area

Tags: android, gps, client, location

I would like to share what i have prepared so far and at the same time ask for assistance and suggestions on the next coding steps needed.

Based from short and basic java and android training and online resources, I have come up with the following theoretical code that has the following objectives (theoretical because I didn’t test it yet):

1. explicitly select the GPS provider (GPS/cell/wifi) to know the phone’s location
2. dislays the current location in a textview
3. connects to a server via 3g
4. sends the latitude, longitude and timestamp as frequently as possible to a server

Below is the code that I prepared:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.location.Criteria;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 public class GpsActivity extends Activity {

private LocationManager lm;
private LocationListener locationListener;
public static TelephonyManager tm;
public static TextView tv;
public static Socket s;
public static PrintWriter out;


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 /**
  * retrieve a reference to provide access to information about the telephony services on the device     
  */
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 /**
  * retrieve a reference to provide access to the system location services    
  */              
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    


/**
 * explicitly select the GPS provider, create a set of Criteria and let android choose the best provider available
 */

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
/**
 * This method takes in four parameters:
provider: The name of the provider with which you register
minTime: The minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds.
minDistance: The minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters.
listener: An object whose onLocationChanged() method will be called for each location update.
 */
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("I currently have no Location Data.");

}

/**
 * Connects the Android Client to a given server
 * 
 * @param name
 *            The name of the remote server
 * @param port
 *            Port number to connect to at the remote server.
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 */
public static void connect(String name, int port)
        throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{

    s = new Socket(name, port);
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
}

/**
 * Sends a string message to the server.
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            The message to be sent.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void send(String msg) throws IOException
{
    if (!s.isClosed() && msg != null)
    {
        out.println(msg);
        if (msg.contains("CMD_QUIT"))
        {
            out.close();
            s.close();
            Log.i("ServerConnection", "Client Disconnected.");
        }
    }
}


private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String txt = "Latitude:" + loc.getLatitude() + "/nLongitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.i("GeoLocation", "My current location is:\n " + txt);
        tv.setText("My current location is:\n" + txt);
        String msg = loc.getLongitude() + "\n" + loc.getLatitude() + "\n"
           + loc.getTime();

    try
        {
        connect("IP address", 27960);
        send("CMD_HELLO");
        send(msg);
        send("CMD_QUIT");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

PLEASE HELP

1. Kindly comment if the code above will meet the four objectives given.
2. HOW CAN I MEET MY 5th objective  ----- I want the android application to start to trigger connecting to server and sending the latitude and longitude only when the phone (being used in a car) is within a road area ( say an area 1km x 30m ). It is continuously listening to its location but will start sending to server once it enters the area and will continuously send and will stop only once it exit the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Your asking the OS to provide the best provider. This would be explict `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,`
2. wont work because you cant update the text view from a listener. Take a look at `android.OS.Handler`
3. technically you meet this, but you'd be better off going with JSON or XML over HTTP rather then inventing your own protocol.
4. Yes

For 5, create two location, a NorthWest location and a SouthEast location that represent your box. In your `onLocationChanged` method, compare the new location with the corners, such that (l.lat > se.lat && l.lat < nw.lat) and (l.lon < se.lon && l.lon > nw.lon) where "l" is the newest location from the callback, "se" is the south east corner of your boundary and "nw" is the north west corner of your bounder. If it meets the 4 above conditions, then you send to your server.

Comment: 1. Thanks user931366 ! appreciate your time, comment and help. You are correct. I think i should have typed "explicitly select the BEST provider (GPS/cell/wifi) to know the phone’s location" because that's what i meant - my bad.                                                  2. ok i'll check that                                                 3. i'm not familiar with JSON or XML , i'll check your suggestion    4. cool                                                                 5. make a lot of sense - i'll verify on the specific area if it can be applied

Comment: Hi user931366. I think your answer for objective 5 is ok when the sides of the rectangular GPS area are parallel to the latitude and longitude lines. What if the rectangular area's sides are not parallel to the latitude and longitude lines.